# Is running Node.js a waste of multicore CPU?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, cluster-analysis

Since Node.js is (seemingly) single threaded (partially for network reasons), does it mean it can only use one CPU core at any time?

Can I even get a single core server these days?

Comment: Do you have any CPU-bound work?

Comment: Maybe. Using a RAM disk, CPU will be the bottle neck soon enough.

Comment: Are you sure that network I/O won't be the bottleneck? Why are you concerned about that which you cannot yet measure (or have not yet measured)?

Comment: I'm concerned because it seems like a big waste to buy a quad core server, and run one single threaded program on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node.js is single threaded, so a single instance of it can only use one core at a time, but there are modules written for utilizing multi-core machines, such as [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). You can also fork processes, using IPC channels to communicate between workers.

Comment: Cluster seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!